# Where we are, how we can improve: what do *you* think about the quality of Arduino SE?

Tags: discussion, content-quality

Averaging over 4K visits a day and a bit under 10 questions per day, we are getting great traffic.

However, now is a good time to talk about the quality of our site. Even if we had 100K visits a day, we still would need to have good quality and a good core group to help moderate the site.

A friendly reminder built in: **this is *your* site that *you* moderate.** Please, feel free to welcome new users, edit poorly formatted questions and answers, and just vote. In addition, [look at your privileges that you are granted (based on your reputation)](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). You have more power than you probably realize, so don't be afraid to talk on meta or [review items in the review queues](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/review). Recently, not many users have been stepping up to these tasks, so make sure to do so or our site will never graduate.

Now, it's your turn to say what you think could be improved? Is our tagging system outdated? Negative tone? Chat rooms should be improved? I want to hear what you have to say!

Comment: For users not familiar with the term, "graduate" means becoming a proper Stack Exchange site. At the moment we're only in beta, which means we're not necessarily here to stay yet.

Answer (score 9):

I think that our "answered percentage" is more than 72%, but we tend to use comments to answer some easy questions. This site is pretty useful and I learned a lot visiting it almost every day, but we should use more the answer box, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I agree. I often see answers shortly posted as comments to the question, without providing further explanation. It is important that people try to answer and provide some more details about the roots of the problem instead of just mentioning "do that, it will work".

Comment: Perhaps some people post brief answers in comments because they don't feel it's up to the quality of a "real" answer, don't have time to discuss it in more detail, and yet don't want to leave things completely unanswered. I think it's fair, if you can expand on such an explanation, to create an answer based on that comment. If you have only a little to add, mark the answer "community wiki" so you don't appear to be unfairly taking credit for a small contribution and perhaps others will add more to it.

Answer (score 7):

Will be a useful site for many.

Overlap with eg SE.EE is unavoidable but should be minimised as much as possible. Some questions are unavoidably Arduino-related but need people with reasonable EE understanding as well. These need to be on the Arduino site, but care should be taken not to let them suffer due to need for EE expertise.

Questions which are transferred between sites **MUST** be treated well.
Posters must be VERY clearly told what has been dome and why, and MUST be able to access and edit and work with their question after the transfer. If transferring a question to another site blocks access to some users you will lose people.

Stack Exchange is too often brutally unfriendly to newcomers. Arduino specifically includes utter electronics beginners in its target demographic. The site must make allowances for this.